# Heroku review apps - switch owner

Tags: heroku

We have review apps enabled for our app in Heroku. The feature was enabled by a developer who no longer works with us. When we revoke his access to the app from which the review apps are build, the review apps are not built any more. If we disable and re-enable the review apps, Heroku assumes we are doing so as the original user so we get an error message that we don't have access to that app...

Is there a way to switch the owner of the automaticlly built review apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the response I got from the Heroku support:

> You can fix this by visiting your pipeline, clicking "Manage GitHub connection", then clicking "Disconnect". Wait a few seconds, refresh the page, and reconnect from the same menu. This will make you the default user for provisioning and deploying review apps.
>
> Once that's done, you'll need to re-enable review apps for your pipeline. Also, if you had any apps set to auto-deploy from GitHub, you'll need to configure that again as well.